# Counting permutations $\pi \in S_n$ such that $\pi(i) \neq i$ and $\pi(i) - k \not\equiv i \bmod n$.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, oeis, derangements

Given integers $n > 2$ and $1 \leq k < n$,
I'm interested in the set of permutations $$
\{\pi \in S_n : \pi(i) \neq i \text{ and } \pi(i) - k \not\equiv i \bmod n\}.
$$

When $k = 1$, these are called ménage permutations (OEIS sequence [A000179](https://oeis.org/A000179)).

I wrote a program to count such permutations, and I have an OEIS sequence ([A354408](https://oeis.org/A354408)),
but looking at the table of data led me to some natural conjectures that I would love to get additional perspective on.

```
  n\k|     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
-----+------------------------------------------------
   2 |     0
   3 |     1     1
   4 |     2     4     2
   5 |    13    13    13    13
   6 |    80    82    80    82    80
   7 |   579   579   579   579   579   579
   8 |  4738  4740  4738  4752  4738  4740  4738
   9 | 43387 43387 43390 43387 43387 43390 43387 43387
```

- In particular, is it true that when $\gcd(n, k) = 1$, the number of restricted
  permutations is equal to the number of ménage permutations? (That is, $A354408(n,k) = A000179(n)$.)
- More specifically, does $A354408(p,k) = A000179(p)$ for all primes $p$?
- With the exception of $A354408(6,3)$, does $\gcd(n,k) \neq 1$ imply that $A354408(n,k) > A000179(n)$?
- Is the first entry in each row the smallest? That is, is it the case that $A354408(n,k) \geq A354408(n,1)$ for all $1 \leq k < n$?
- Is there a pattern to which value of $k$ maximizes $A354408(n,k)$?
- Can we find a decent bound on the difference between the smallest and largest values in each row, $d(n) = \max_k A354408(n,k) - \min_k A354408(n,k)$?

Comment: The first two questions definitely have affirmative answers.  If $\gcd(n,k) = 1$ then $\pi_k(i) \equiv ki \pmod{n}$ defines a permutation $\pi_k \in S_n$.  With this permutation in hand, we note that there is a bijection from the ménage permutations to your restricted permutations given by the conjugation $\sigma \mapsto \pi_k\sigma\pi_k^{-1}$.

Comment: That's a great point, Brian. If you want to put that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Generalizing the first question, we have $A354408(n,j)=A354408(n,k)$ if $\gcd(n,j)=\gcd(n,k)$. The proof is similar to Brian's proof for the case $j=1$, using conjugation by $\pi_m$, where $j=mk\pmod n$ and $\gcd(n,m)=1$. (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4169317) for the existence of such an $m$.)

Comment: Empirically, it seems that $A354408(n,j)<A354408(n,k)$ if $\gcd(n,j)<\gcd(n,k)$, with an exception for $n=6$, $k=3$. If true, it would follow that (for $n\ne6$), $A354408(n,k)$ is minimized when $k=1$ (or any number coprime to $n$) and maximized when $k$ is the largest proper divisor of $n$ (or any multiple thereof between $0$ and $n$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to look at this problem is extensions of $2 \times n$ Latin rectangles to $3 \times n$ Latin rectangles.  In particular, the ménage problem asks the number of ways to do it when the first rows are:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
\color{blue} 2 & \color{blue} 3 & \color{blue} 4 & \color{blue} 5 & \color{blue} 6 & \color{blue} 7 & \color{blue} 8 & \color{blue} 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is the $k=1$ case, and the given generalization allows for different second rows, such as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
\color{blue} 4 & \color{blue} 5 & \color{blue} 6 & \color{blue} 7 & \color{blue} 8 & \color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 2 & \color{blue} 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is the $k=3$ case.  $2$-row Latin rectangles are defined by their cycle structure, up to isotopism.  E.g. if we treat the above two Latin rectangles as permutations (where the elements in row 1 map to the elements in row 2), then we have the permutations $(12345678)$ and $(14725836)$.  You can use these permutations to permute the columns and symbols of the first Latin rectangle above, to give the second Latin rectangle above---thus they have the same number of extensions to a $3 \times n$ Latin rectangle, and the same A354408-value.  This is one way to show that if $\gcd(k_1,n)=\gcd(k_2,n)$ then $A354408(n,k_1)=A354408(n,k_2)$, and in particular $A354408(n,k)=A000179(n)$ whenever $\gcd(n,k)=1$.

In cases when $\gcd(k,n) \neq 1$, we get a non-isotopic Latin rectangle, such as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
\color{blue} 3 & \color{blue} 4 & \color{blue} 5 & \color{blue} 6 & \color{blue} 7 & \color{blue} 8 & \color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $k=2$, which corresponds to the permutation $(1357)(2468)$.

Some thoughts:

- It's likely (or, as Zeilberger puts it: *by general ‘hand-waving’ (that can be easily made rigorous)*) for fixed $k$ that these numbers satisfy linear recurrence with polynomial coefficients (i.e. [P-recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-recursive_equation)).  In fact, when $k=1$ (the ménage problem) we have

  $$a(n) = n a(n-1) + 2 a(n-2) - (n-4) a(n-3) - a(n-4)$$

  where $a(n)=A354408(n,1)$ and $n \geq 6$ (adapted from the recurrence given in Sloane's [A000179](http://oeis.org/A000179)), and when $k=2$ we have

  $$b(n) = n b(n-1) + 3 b(n-2) + (-2n+6) b(n-3) - 3 b(n-4) + (n-6) b(n-5) + b(n-6)$$

  where $b(n)=A354408(n,2)$ (Sloane's [A354152](http://oeis.org/A354152) reports that this was proved by Doron Zeilberger's computer in *Automatic Enumeration of Generalized Menage Numbers* ([pdf](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.1089))).

  By applying induction on $b(n)-a(n)$ (it's fiddly), we find:
  $$
    b(n) = \begin{cases} a(n) & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\ a(n)+2 & \text{if $n$ is even} \end{cases}
    $$
  which implies that if $\gcd(n,k)=2$ then $A354408(n,k) = b(n) > a(n) = A354408(n,1)$.
- By far the best way to compute the number of $k \times n$ Latin rectangles for fixed $k$ (assuming we don't have a recurrence) is Doyle's formula ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703896v1)) (which I wrote about [here](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00373-015-1643-1)).  If it could be adapted to this problem, it'd save a considerable amount of computation time.  I'm not sure if this is possible.
- I'm not 100% sure, but I think this generalization of the ménage problem was studied by [Vladimir Shevelev](https://www.math.bgu.ac.il/%7Eshevelev/) in:

  > V. S. Shevelev, A generalized Riordan formula for three-rowed Latin rectangles and its applications, DAN of the Ukraine, 2 (1991), 8-12 (in Russian).
- These numbers are also permanents of $(0,1)$-matrices, such as when $n=8$, the numbers are
  $$
  \mathrm{per}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \qquad
  \mathrm{per}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  $$
  when $k=1$ and $k=2$.  Since permanents are invariant under row and column permutations, it can be easier to view some of the properties in this context.

  In this way, we observe that when $n$ is even, then $A354408(n,n/2)=A003471(n)$ (Sloane's [A003471](http://oeis.org/A003471)).
- When $n=10$, the numbers are $A354408(10,1)=439792$, $A354408(10,2)=439794$, and $A354408(10,5)=440192$, and when $n=12$, the numbers are $A354408(12,1)=59216642$, $A354408(12,2)=59216644$, $A354408(12,3)=59216648$, $A354408(12,4)=59216968$, and $A354408(12,6)=59245120$.